# Owing to or thanks to

Tags: word-choice

__________ to Gail, I managed to finish the project on time.

a) Owing

b) Thanks

And why?

Comment: "Because of"  has a sweet ring.  It's sure and deferential.  Thanks is ok, but "owing" sounds official and detached.  This is just an opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, this usage, they mean the same thing.  The dictionary exactly lists the definition of "thanks to" as "owing to."

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thanks?s=t